# Expression to change an attribute each X number of rows

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, expression

I'm using QGIS and I need an expression to change an attribute each X number of rows.
For instance I have the next attribute data:

[image]

I want to create an attribute (C) that assigns an ordered value each 3 rows. With the next result:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your rows are already sorted, you just have to create a new integer field with the expression: `($rownum + 1) / 3`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I needed and I didn't figure it out :-(